# MassTransit. Kafka. How to produce message from saga state machine, during message processing

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, masstransit, saga

PublishAsync not work

Example program.cs:

```cs
namespace MassTransitKafka
{
    class Program
    {
        private static ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
                
                x.AddRider(rider =>
                {
                    rider.AddProducer<Enter1>(nameof(Enter1));
                    rider.AddProducer<Enter2>(nameof(Enter2));
                    rider.AddProducer<Enter3>(nameof(Enter3));
                    rider.AddProducer<EnterEnter>(nameof(EnterEnter));
                    rider.AddSagaStateMachine<TestSaga1StateMachine, TestSaga1State>(typeof(TestSaga1StateDefinition))
                        .InMemoryRepository();
                    
                    rider.UsingKafka((context, k) =>
                    {
                        k.Host("localhost:9092");
                        
                        k.TopicEndpoint<Null, Enter1>(nameof(Enter1), nameof(TestSaga1StateMachine), c =>
                        {
                            c.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                            c.ConfigureSaga<TestSaga1State>(context);
                        });
                        k.TopicEndpoint<Null, Enter2>(nameof(Enter2), nameof(TestSaga1StateMachine), c =>
                        {
                            c.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                            c.ConfigureSaga<TestSaga1State>(context);
                        });
                        k.TopicEndpoint<Null, Enter3>(nameof(Enter3), nameof(TestSaga1StateMachine), c =>
                        {
                            c.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                            c.ConfigureSaga<TestSaga1State>(context);
                        });
                        k.TopicEndpoint<Null, EnterEnter>(nameof(EnterEnter), nameof(TestSaga1StateMachine), c =>
                        {
                            c.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                            c.ConfigureSaga<TestSaga1State>(context);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var busControl = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>();
            var observer = new ReceiveObserver();
            busControl.ConnectReceiveObserver(observer);

            await busControl.StartAsync();
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
            {
                Work(busControl, tokenSource.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            });
            
            while (true)
            {
                var quit = Console.ReadLine();
                if (quit == "quit")
                {
                    tokenSource.Cancel();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task Work(IPublishEndpoint publisher, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid();
            var enter1Producer = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITopicProducer<Enter1>>();
            
            await enter1Producer.Produce(new {CorrelationId = correlationId, EnteredText = "1"}, token);

            while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                var cancelled = token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(5000);
                if (cancelled)
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        private static Dictionary<string, string> Configuration
        {
            get
            {
                return new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092" },
                    { "group.id", "saga.group.id" }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example TestSaga1StateMachine.cs

```
    public class TestSaga1StateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<TestSaga1State>
    {
        public TestSaga1StateMachine()
        {
            InstanceState(_ => _.CurrentState);
            Event(() => Enter1Event, x => x.CorrelateById(ctx => ctx.Message.CorrelationId));
            Event(() => Enter2Event, x => x.CorrelateById(ctx => ctx.Message.CorrelationId));
            Event(() => Enter3Event, x => x.CorrelateById(ctx => ctx.Message.CorrelationId));
            Event(() => EnterEnterEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(ctx => ctx.Message.CorrelationId));

            Initially(
                When(Enter1Event)
                    .Then(context => context.Instance.SaveEnter1(context.Data))
// Messages are not sent here
                    .PublishAsync(context => context.Init<Enter2>(new {EnteredText = "2"}))
                    .TransitionTo(Entered1)
                );
            During(Entered1,
                When(Enter2Event)
                    .Then(context => context.Instance.SaveEnter2(context.Data))
// Messages are not sent here
                    .PublishAsync(context => context.Init<Enter3>(new {EnteredText = "3"}))
                    .TransitionTo(Entered2)
                );
            During(Entered2,
                When(Enter3Event)
                    .Then(context => context.Instance.SaveEnter3(context.Data))
// Messages are not sent here
                    .PublishAsync(context => context.Init<EnterEnter>(new {EnteredText = "Enter"}))
                    .TransitionTo(Entered3)
            );
            During(Entered3,
                When(EnterEnterEvent)
                    .Then(context => context.Instance.Print())
                    .TransitionTo(EnteredEnter)
                    .Finalize());

            SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
        }
        
        public State Entered1 { get; set; }
        public State Entered2 { get; set; }
        public State Entered3 { get; set; }
        public State EnteredEnter { get; set; }
        
        public Event<Enter1> Enter1Event { get; set; }
        public Event<Enter2> Enter2Event { get; set; }
        public Event<Enter3> Enter3Event { get; set; }
        public Event<EnterEnter> EnterEnterEvent { get; set; }
    }
```

This project is just for my learning.
I don't understand how to produce message up there
The bus configuration is identical to the one in the documentation. The first Enter1 message is published successfully and the saga receives it, but how to send a message to kafka from the saga is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a custom state machine activity, with a dependency on the *producer* interface (setup when Kafka is configured), in order to produce messages to Kafka topics. I recently did a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5aKFOz3unM&list=PLx8uyNNs1ri1UA_Nerr7Ej3g9nT2PxbbH&index=6) on this as part of Season 2.

You can see an example of producer setup in the [unit tests](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.KafkaIntegration.Tests/Producer_Specs.cs#L36)

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        rider.AddProducer<KafkaMessage>(Topic);

        rider.UsingKafka((context, k) =>
        {
            k.Host("localhost:9092");
        });
    });
});
```

Then, in your custom state machine activity, you'd add a constructor dependency on on `ITopicProducer<KafkaMessage>` and use that to produce the message. It may look similar to [this one](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Library/blob/master/src/Library.Components/StateMachines/NotifyMemberActivity.cs):

```
public class ProduceEnter2Activity :
    Activity<TestSaga1State>
{
    readonly ITopicProducer<Enter2> _producer;

    public ProduceEnter2Activity(ITopicProducer<Enter2> producer)
    {
        _producer = producer;
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateScope("notifyMember");
    }

    public void Accept(StateMachineVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }

    public async Task Execute(BehaviorContext<TestSaga1State> context, Behavior<TestSaga1State> next)
    {
        await Execute(context);

        await next.Execute(context);
    }

    public async Task Execute<T>(BehaviorContext<TestSaga1State, T> context, Behavior<TestSaga1State, T> next)
    {
        await Execute(context);

        await next.Execute(context);
    }

    public Task Faulted<TException>(BehaviorExceptionContext<TestSaga1State, TException> context, Behavior<TestSaga1State> next)
        where TException : Exception
    {
        return next.Faulted(context);
    }

    public Task Faulted<T, TException>(BehaviorExceptionContext<TestSaga1State, T, TException> context, Behavior<TestSaga1State, T> next)
        where TException : Exception
    {
        return next.Faulted(context);
    }

    async Task Execute(BehaviorContext<TestSaga1State> context)
    {
        await _producer.Produce(new Enter2(...));
    }
}
```

Then, in your state machine, you would use:

```
.Activity(x => x.OfInstanceType<ProduceEnter2Activity>())
```

Comment: producers is configured and messages are published, but inside state machine are not.
Sorry for bad english

Comment: Creation of producers inside the state machine may help? Something like this:
var config = new ProducerConfig {BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"};
            var p = new ProducerBuilder<Null, Enter1>(config)
                .SetValueSerializer(new MassTransitJsonSerializer<Enter1>())
                .Build();

Comment: No, you should not do that. You need to configure the Kafka rider, as shown in the documentation (or that unit test) and then use the producer to publish to the Kafka topics. Riders do not support send/publish, you must use a producer.

Comment: I'm added an constructor dependency on ITopicProducer<KafkaMessage> and got exception occurred during bus creation "The ReceivePipeConfiguration can only be used once."

Comment: Can you update your question with the entire configuration code?

Comment: Thank you very much Chris for your time. You helped me

Comment: @Domer Hey. Why did u get "The ReceivePipeConfiguration can only be used once"? I kinda have the same problem, when i'm trying to get and use one of the services like ibuscontrol or imessagescheduler from a container on startup. There are basically no info on this error.

Comment: @L1GhTUA Hey. I tried to inject into the constructor of the state machine the producer ITopicProducer <KafkaMessage>